# It returns none when I get the id of the url using beatiful soup and how could i get the content of its id

Tags: python

It returns none when I get the id of the url using Beautiful Soup and how could I get the content of its id

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Ozeri-Digital-Multifunction-Kitchen-Elegant/dp/B01LAVADW2?pf_rd_p=3e7c8265-9bb7-5ab2-be71-1af95f06a1ad&pf_rd_r=52Z7DNQGKGV31B114R1K&pd_rd_wg=IAKey&ref_=pd_gw_ri&pd_rd_w=rDONb&pd_rd_r=b6b3cf66-c4a8-449a-8676-9027e8922b96'
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.100 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle")

print(title)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, and do some research. Have you read the BeautifulSoup docs?

Answer (score 0):

you have created a variable headers, but you didn't add it to your request, also, you are not checking your request response status code (which is 503)

fixing your code it should look something like this:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Ozeri-Digital-Multifunction-Kitchen-Elegant/dp/B01LAVADW2?pf_rd_p=3e7c8265-9bb7-5ab2-be71-1af95f06a1ad&pf_rd_r=52Z7DNQGKGV31B114R1K&pd_rd_wg=IAKey&ref_=pd_gw_ri&pd_rd_w=rDONb&pd_rd_r=b6b3cf66-c4a8-449a-8676-9027e8922b96'
headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.100 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
    print(title.next)
```